# How to access XUL Overlay's DOM

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, firefox-addon

In my Firefox Addon's `overlay.xul`, can I access it's DOM in javascript? I can't figure out how.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From script in a webpage or script in your XPI?

Comment: Did you try document.getElementById()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An overlay is merged with the DOM of the document that it applies to, it doesn't have a DOM of its own. So you don't access the DOM of "the overlay", you access the DOM of the document that you overlaid. And that is being done the usual way, e.g. via `document.getElementById()`. You have to consider one thing however: never access the DOM before the document finished loading, this will cause various issues (like other overlays failing to apply). So if your overlay includes a script you can write:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  // Window finished loading, now we can do something
  var button = document.getElementById("my-extension-button");
  button.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}, false)
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to use a `<browser />` tag in an overlay? I want to use and manipulate a `<browser />` in the background.

Comment: @NeXXeuS: Do you mean the "normal" browser? It is accessible as `gBrowser` (a global variable). Or you can add your own browser of course, you need to add it to your overlay then (choose some insertion point in the document you apply the overlay to).